# ios-sim in Jenkins Process leaked file descriptors

Tags: jenkins, ios-simulator

I am getting a file leak descriptors in Jenkins when trying to launch ios-sim using the shell. Something I should mention is that I changed the user of Jenkins to my user away from the initially installed "/Users/Shared/Jenkins" location. Here's the message

> - ./ios-sim launch /Users/me/Desktop/tmp/iOS.app --sdk 6.0 --family iphone
>     Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more

The link states it may be due to not being able to detect the EOF. If so how can point Jenkins to write to "stdin/stdout/stderr"?

Is it a matter of chowning some files that I may of missed when I moved the "/User/Shared/Jenkins/Home" location to /Users/me/Jenkins/Home and the "/Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war" file to "/User/me/Applications/jenkins.war" ?

In addition to those moves I updated the org.jenkins-ci.plist as follows:

```
    <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log</string>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
            <key>JENKINS_HOME</key>
            <string>/Users/me/Jenkins/Home</string>
    </dict>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>staff</string>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.jenkins-ci</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
            <string>/bin/bash</string>
            <string>/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>me</string>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true />
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm using Jenkins version 1.499

And here is the jenkins.log error:

```
WARNING: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
java.lang.Exception
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:329)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:360)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:91)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:60)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:810)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:592)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1543)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Insane in the membrane" why is it advertised everywhere to stop start and stop jenkins using:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

???? Who wants to edit the jenkins-runner.sh or the add values to the .plist file???? boooo

The secret is in the secret user jenkins created upon install in the "/Users/me/.jenkins" location.

You need to own all the processes and in order to that just locate the jenkins.war file and launch it like so:

```
nohup java -jar ~/.jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=8080
```

Suddenly everything starts working under the user on your company machine!

enjoy